# ¿Problema al instalar bcftools en MAC o problema con C: [ploidy.o] Error 1?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, gcc

Quisiera algo de ayuda.
Estoy trantando de instalar algo llamado [bcftools](https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/). Después de descargar todo, al hacer make, tengo el siguiente error:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Carlos:bcftools carlosvasquezguerra$ make
echo '#define BCFTOOLS_VERSION "1.9-117-g9e81e92"' > version.h
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfindex.o vcfindex.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o tabix.o tabix.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfstats.o vcfstats.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfisec.o vcfisec.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfmerge.o vcfmerge.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfquery.o vcfquery.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcffilter.o vcffilter.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib    -c -o filter.o filter.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfsom.o vcfsom.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfnorm.o vcfnorm.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfgtcheck.o vcfgtcheck.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfview.o vcfview.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfannotate.o vcfannotate.c
vcfannotate.c: In function ‘setter_info_str’:
vcfannotate.c:854:59: warning: request for implicit conversion from ‘void *’ to ‘struct kh_str2int_t *’ not permitted in C++ [-Wc++-compat]
                 if ( !col->mm_str_hash ) col->mm_str_hash = khash_str2int_init();
                                                           ^
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfroh.o vcfroh.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfconcat.o vcfconcat.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfcall.o vcfcall.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o mcall.o mcall.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcmp.o vcmp.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o gvcf.o gvcf.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o reheader.o reheader.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o convert.o convert.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfconvert.o vcfconvert.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o tsv2vcf.o tsv2vcf.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o vcfcnv.o vcfcnv.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o HMM.o HMM.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib  -DPLUGINPATH='"/usr/local/libexec/bcftools"' -c -o vcfplugin.o vcfplugin.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o consensus.o consensus.c
gcc -g -Wall -Wc++-compat -O2 -I. -I../htslib   -c -o ploidy.o ploidy.c
In file included from /usr/include/Availability.h:232:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:61,
                 from ../htslib/htslib/khash.h:128,
                 from ../htslib/htslib/khash_str2int.h:28,
                 from ploidy.c:25:
/usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h:33:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __has_include(<AvailabilityInternalPrivate.h>)
                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:61:0,
                 from ../htslib/htslib/khash.h:128,
                 from ../htslib/htslib/khash_str2int.h:28,
                 from ploidy.c:25:
/usr/include/Availability.h:493:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __has_include(<AvailabilityProhibitedInternal.h>)
                  ^
make: *** [ploidy.o] Error 1
```

Ya estuve consultando con algunos amigos y no tienen este problema con la misma versión de MAC: Mojave :10.14.3. Además de que preferiría no instalar una maquina virtual por el hecho de que sí se ha podido instalar esto en otros equipos similares.

Igual agrego las dependencias que tengo instaladas con brew:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Carlos:bcftools carlosvasquezguerra$ brew list
atk             icu4c
autoconf            isl
automake            jpeg
cairo               libepoxy
fontconfig          libffi
freetype            libmpc
fribidi             libpng
gdbm                libtiff
gdk-pixbuf          mpfr
gettext             ncurses
git-flow-avh            openssl
glib                pango
gmp             pcre
gnu-getopt          pixman
graphite2           pkg-config
gsettings-desktop-schemas   python
gtk+                readline
gtk+3               sqlite
harfbuzz            xz
hicolor-icon-theme      zlib
```

Nota: Versión Xcode: Xcode-select version 2354

Espero que me puedan ayudar con este problema, gracias.

Comment: te recomiendo que pongas los códigos de error como texto, pues como tu ventana de cmd tiene transparencia incluso se lee la pregunta que estabas redactando aquí en SO en español

Comment: Claro, gracias.

Comment: ¿ Que versión de `gcc` estás usando ?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 4.8.5

Comment: Que sistema operativo tienes? Linux o Mac? Y si Linux, cual? Seguro que hace falta compilarlo?

Comment: Es una Mac, la versión del OS la deje arriba comentada y sí; el objetivo es que al final pueda usar bcftools, claro, después de hacer la variable de entorno; pero después de hacer el `make` , si se hace la variable, no se reconoce aún el comando `bfctools`